# Drawing Font Effects (Underline, Strickeout) freetype Library and OpenGl

Tags: c++, opengl, freetype

I use this link to draw text with a specific Font using freeType Library:

http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/freetype_fonts_in_opengl/24001/

How can I underline or strikeout text?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I can with my program draw (italic/ bold) font by creating "mapping table": font name -> font file (trueType).
Now I try to make underlined text or a strickeout one, but i don't know how using openGl !!

Comment: You didn't answer Joachim's question. What have you tried in terms of researching how to make underlined/strike-through text?

Comment: yes, I need to underline or strickeout a text drawing in openGL

Comment: @TasnimHd: He's asking if you actually attempted to implement this yourself. If you haven't, you should attempt to do it on your own, and then ask if it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "font effect" is nothing more than drawing text and then drawing something on top of it. An underline font is exactly what it looks like: drawing text, then drawing a line under it. In the case of OpenGL, you would use line rendering. Strikethrough is simply a matter of drawing that light *higher*.

The only real question is where to draw the line. For underlines, you draw it at the baseline. For strikethrough, you draw it maybe 2/5ths of the way from the baseline to the top. Or whatever looks good.